# USB-C Extension Cable

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, video

I was looking around the web for a USB type C male to USB type C female extension cable, and could not find one. Does such a product exist? I have set up Apple's AV adapter for the new MacBook at my TV, but want to be able to hide it away and run one wire up to easily connect my mac to. The wire built in to the adapter is very short (a few inches). Does any such extension cable exist, that anyone here is aware of? Thanks in advance!